# Using command line arguments to extract from txt file and run specific classes in C++

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a project that needs to be run with either of the following commands:

./project.exe -Stack < [filename]

./project.exe -Queue < [filename]

I am wondering why there is a - in front of both Stack and Queue and why the filename is preceded by < and is in brackets.

The purpose of this format is to tell the program to either run using a stack class or run using a queue class. I will also need to extract the information from the text file mentioned in the command line.

I am familiar with general command line arguments and how to use them, but I have never seen this notation before and can't find any clear explanations.

Comment: this completely depends on what `project.exe` is. A program may choose any format for its comand line parameters it likes to choose. You could write a program that uses `42` as prefix for command line parameters

Comment: you have to ask the person who wrote `project.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash for the options are simply a common convention. Usually with modern command-line programs one uses double-dash for so-called *long* options (like e.g. `--stack`) and single dash for *short* options (e.g. `-s`).

Many existing argument parsers, like the [Linux `getopt_long` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), actually requires the single or double dashes for short and long options to be recognized as such.

The `<` is *file redirection*. It tells the shell to redirect the programs standard input from the file. Inside the program you can read from standard input (`std::cin`) and it will be automatically reading from the file. This redirection is handled entirely by the shell.